# Assign shortcut to modifier key(s) only

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut

Is it possible to use modifier keys alone as shortcuts in OS X El Capitan? Coming from Windows background I would like a single press on Command button (without touching Space or anything) to show Spotlight search and Ctrl + Shift to switch keyboard language.

UPDATE: Let me clarify, a single press on Command button is press/release so the key would not be interpreted as a start of a longer shortcut sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quicksilver](https://qsapp.com) does it for me for years now - as it comes especially handy for multilingual use. Just select Modifier-only activation and you are good to go.

Looking for a native solution though, in fact, this is how I ran into this post.

Comment: Adding a link to the resource you reference in your answer would be helpful.